# switch object between two js python

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so I have this which works fine, but my brain is dead and I'm sure there is a better way to write this:

```js
// show results
let rtwEventList = $('#rtw-event-list'),
   rtwCharityList = $('#rtw-charity-list');

$("#rtw-results").text({{ event_total }} + ' Results');

function showTotal(){
   $(rtwEventList).click(function() {
        $("#rtw-results").text({{ event_total }} + ' Results');
   });
   $(rtwCharityList).click(function() {
        $("#rtw-results").text({{ charity_total }} + ' Results');
   })

}

showTotal()
```

Maybe going down the ternary conditions/expressions option might be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
     $(rtwEventList).click(function() {
            showTotal();
       });
       $(rtwCharityList).click(function() {
            showTotal();
       })
        function showTotal(){

            if(condition){
                $("#rtw-results").text({{ charity_total }} + ' Results');
            } else {
                $("#rtw-results").text({{ event_total }} + ' Results');
            }

   }
```